# Back up to Time Capsule remotely via SSH + iMac

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, backup, time-capsule

I wonder if it's possible to connect from my MacBook at home to my iMac at work, using SSH and then bind 'whateverport' to my Time Capsule (placed at work) so I can backup my MacBook from home as well?

I often SSH in to my work computer to monitor and transfer files, but this time I need to acces the time capsule. It feels like `ssh L 1201:127.0.0.1:548 me@mydomain.se` isn't too far from it?

This would definitely make my weekend!

Comment: i mean you can, but ssh turns out to be pretty slow with uploading in comparison to other sharing protocols, and any remote backup is slow, so if you're planning on storing more than about 5-10gb then i wouldnt recomend it

Answer (score 0):

If you need time machine like backup to remote server (big ping), it is really better to use third party tool. http://immortalfiles.com/ is doing it and it will cost you nothing. Also much better inclusion/exclusion when default time machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing out this simple bash script:

https://github.com/hypery2k/timemachine-ssh

it works, but, when I am working from remote, performance seems to be awfully slow, far slower than the amount of data ssh is sending.
It works better when I am on the same network as the TM server (where tunneling wouldn't be necessary) but I think it is just because I have much higher bandwidth.
I don't think it's a matter of sheer amount of data you're sending, it seems that sending many small files (like the ones a software developer modifies every minute) definitely kills performance, more than it would be reasonable.